# Where does the function go in a JSX class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am trying to put this function in my React class component just to make sure the button works. But I am having difficulty figuring out where the function should go.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SUBJECT from "./subject";
import GENRE from "./genre";

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      subject: SUBJECT,
      genre: GENRE
    };
    
    function tester () { 
      alert('the button works'); 
  }

  render() {
    return <button onlick='tester'()>Click me</button>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Put it above the class.

Comment: The function does not depend on react, so can be outside React Class Component. Can be in a separate file if other parts of your project want it and you like organizing stuff.

Comment: remove the word function

Answer (score 3):

You can put the function inside the react class component like this.

```
    tester = () => { 
       alert('the button works'); 
    }

    render() {
    return (
         <button onlick={this.tester}>Click me</button>
       );      
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, and read mode about Handling Events from here [Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

```
test() {
  alert("the button works");
} 
render() {
  return <button onClick={this.test}>Click me</button>;
}
```